# MS Access 2016 Record count with subquery count with percent result

Tags: microsoft-access, query

I have a query that counts the number of records in a table that contains a number of repair tickets, and the result is the number of repair tickets by company that have been completed.
Example;
Companycode | CompnayName | CountOfTickets

```
SELECT 
Incident.CompanyCode, Count(Incident.CompanyCode) AS IncCount
FROM 
Incident
GROUP BY
Incident.CompanyCode, Incident.IncidentType, Incident.IncidentClosed
HAVING
(((Incident.IncidentType)="On - Site") AND 
((Incident.IncidentClosed)=True));
```

Now, what I am having a hard time getting my head wrapped around is this.
Each of the records being counted has a field for marking the ticket as having been meeting an SLA. The field is a text field with either a "Y" or an "N".

What I am trying to do is count the number of records within the query above, that meets the criteria of either a "Y" or an "N", and then divide that result by the count of the main query to get a percentage of repair tickets that match the criteria.
So, out of x number of repair tickets for company xyz, x% have met the SLA.

I know this would likely involve a sub-query, but I am not sure how to code it or where to put the sub-query.

I would like to have the result as part of the same result table ie..
Companycode | CompnayName | CountOfTickets | % Met SLA

I don't know if the solution would be a simple one or not, but I have been working on this for sometime now and I just can't see it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to review this post and for any help that is given.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CompanyName, 
    CompanyCode, 
    Count(*), 
    Sum(iif(MetSLA, 1, 0))/Count(*) * 100
FROM 
    Incident
WHERE 
    IncidentType = "On - Site" 
    AND IncidentClosed = Yes
GROUP BY 
    CompanyName, CompanyCode;
```

Explanation: the `Sum(iif(MetSLA, 1, 0))` expression effectively counts rows where the MetSLA flag is set (true/yes). `Sum` is applied as an aggregate function after the rows are grouped (like `Count` is). Thus, you get a count of MetSLA=yes rows as a percentage of rows for that company (since the grouping is by company).